# cascading dropdown angularjs mvc

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, model-view-controller, .net-core

i am getting null values

```
 $scope.GetDepartment = function (Department) {
        $http.get('/Official/GetDepartment?Department=' + Department).then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.department= data.data;
        });
    };
```

Html

```
  <select ng-model="empModel.division" id="" name="Division" class="form-control"   
                                ng-click = "GetDepartment(empModel.division)"  
                                ng-change = "GetDepartment(empModel.division)"
                                ng-options="c.division as c.division for c in division" >
                            <option selected="selected">Select</option>
                        </select>

 <select ng-model="empModel.department" id="" name="Department" class="form-control"
                                    ng-options="d.department as d.department for d in department">
                                <option></option>
                            </select>
```

When i select divison i am not getting anything in department dropdown
Controller

```
  public JsonResult GetDepartment(string Department)
    {
        var department = db.Depts.Where(x => x.Department == Department).
            GroupBy(x => x.Department).
            Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).
            OrderBy(x => x.Department).ToList();

        return Json(department);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your angular part for retrieve division data

```
    function GetDesignation(input) {
        $http.get('/Official/GetDesignation?designation='+input).then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.designation = data.data;
        });

    };
```

change in HTML using ng-change directive there

```
  <select ng-model="empModel.division" id="" name="Division" class="form-control" ng-change = "GetDesignation(empModel.division)"
                                    ng-options="c.division as c.division for c in division" >
                                <option></option>
                            </select>
```

New HTML tag for load Designation data in dropdown

```
  <select ng-model="empModel.designation" id="" name="Designation" class="form-control" 
                                    ng-options="c.designation as c.designation for c in designation" >
                                <option></option>
                            </select>
```

Comment: what will html  code for designation? is it same like division?

Comment: yes actually almost same. you have to bind that variable designation instead of division, that the diff here.

Comment: i have just added code that you provide me its still not working and i find out that when i change division its not calling my controller /Official/GetDesignation ??

Comment: if this answer is useful for you can it get the accepted and a upvote so that other people will be able to use it also?

Comment: need to ask one more thing how i can add default value in dropdown for example i need to show 1st division in dropdown, currently default value show empty dropdown

Comment: yes you can do that. in your case you can remove the option tag inside select and check it again.

Comment: just removed option tag still same issue

Comment: add this line inside GetDesignation function after getting `$scope.designation` data
`$scope.empModel.designation = $scope.designation[0].designation;`

Comment: i am getting this error : TypeError: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference

Comment: ok actually you are sending for division and you wrote designation, this code worked for division, now how i can get designation list default vaue?

Comment: ya I wrote for designation as I supplied you code for designation. this is applicable for both of your dropdown. same as it worked for division. If that do not work for designation share that code here.

Comment: `$scope.GetDesignation = function (Designation) {  

            $scope.empModel.designation = $scope.designation[0].designation; 
            $http.get('/Official/GetDesignation?Designation=' + Designation).then(function (data) {
              
                console.log(data);
                $scope.designation = data.data;
                $scope.empModel.designation = $scope.designation[0].designation;
               
            });
          

        };`  i am getting this error - TypeError: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference.

Comment: looks like you used `$scope.empModel.designation = $scope.designation[0].designation;` twice. remove the first one and keep that code after `$scope.designation = data.data;` like 
`$scope.GetDesignation = function (Designation) 
{ 
    $http.get('/Official/GetDesignation?Designation=' + Designation).
    then(function (data) { console.log(data); 
    $scope.designation = data.data; 
    $scope.empModel.designation = $scope.designation[0].designation; 
    }); 
};`

Comment: perfect its all good if i have any other question i will post new one thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks for accepting and hoping a upvote also from you. :)

Comment: can you check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48736223/why-getting-value-like-this-1-angularjs