# Why getting value like this [1] in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to get id from table but I am getting id like this `[1]`. I need to get `1` only.

Controller

```
 public JsonResult GetLineManagerId(string LineManagerId)
        {
var lineManagerId = db.Employees
       .Where(x => x.FirstName == LineManagerId)
       .Select(x =>x.Id);
            return Json(lineManagerId);
        }
```

Angular

```
$scope.GetLineManagerId = function (LineManagerId) {
            $http.get('/Official/GetLineManagerId?LineManagerId=' + LineManagerId).then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.lineManagerId = data.data;
                $scope.empModel.lineManagerId = $scope.lineManagerId[0].lineManagerId;

            });
        };
```

html

```
 <select ng-model="empModel.name" id="" name="Name" class="form-control" 
                                    ng-change="GetLineManagerId(empModel.name)"
                                    ng-click="GetLineManagerId(empModel.name)"
                                    ng-options="d.name as d.name for d in name">
                                <option></option>


     </select> 
  <select ng-model="empModel.id" id="" name="Id" class="form-control"
                                  >
                                <option>{{lineManagerId}}</option>
                            </select>
```

when I click on 1st dropdown I get id like this `[1]`.. I need to get number only like this `1`

I need to get id number in dropdown, also if someone help me to get id in text input instead of using dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, Please don't use ng-click here

```
 <select ng-model="empModel.name" id="" name="Name" class="form-control" 
                                    ng-change="GetLineManagerId(empModel.name)"
                                    ng-options="d.name as d.name for d in name">
                                <option></option>
```

Load linemanager using this

```
  <select ng-model="empModel.id" id="" name="Id" class="form-control"
                                ng-options="d.lineManagerId as d.lineManagerId for d in lineManagerId"
                                  >
                             <option></option>   
                            </select>
```

your other portion will remain unchanged I think

Comment: its worked fine, but how i can get default value when i select name? currently when i select name i get the in dropdown but 1st value always empty and 2nd value is id

Comment: did you update according to my answer or you want to try in your way? I am asking because to know current condition of code.

Comment: another thing is your first dropdown loading properly?

Comment: i ddi exactly like your code everything seems fine but id not showing in dropdown

Comment: angular `$scope.GetLineManagerId = function (LineManagerId) {


            $http.get('/Official/GetLineManagerId?LineManagerId=' + LineManagerId).then(function (data) {

                console.log(data);
                $scope.lineManagerId = data.data;
             

            });`

Comment: html `<select ng-model="empModel.name" id="" name="Name" 
                                    ng-change="GetLineManagerId(empModel.name)"
                                    ng-options="d.name as d.name for d in name">
                                <option></option>
                                </select>
                            <select ng-model="empModel.id" id="" name="Id" 
                                    ng-options="d.lineManagerId as d.lineManagerId for d in lineManagerId">
                             
                            </select>`

Comment: 1st dropdown loading properly but not 2nd dropdown

Comment: just change the given angular function like below. then let me know if it works or not.

`$scope.GetLineManagerId = function (LineManagerId) 
{ 
  $http.get('/Official/GetLineManagerId?LineManagerId=' + LineManagerId).
  then(function (data) { console.log(data); 
  $scope.lineManagerId = data.data; 
  $scope.empModel.id = $scope.lineManagerId[0].lineManagerId;

});`

Comment: still same issue and i m getting this error in console "Unable to get property 'lineManagerId' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: can you mention the result of console.log(data) of ur function?

Comment: {config: Object {...}, data: 1, status: 200, statusText: "", xhrStatus: "complete"}

Comment: sorry again,  now can u again share ur c# code again?

Comment: `public JsonResult GetLineManagerId(string LineManagerId)
        {
           var lineManagerId = db.Employees
        .Where(x => x.FirstName == LineManagerId)
        .Select(x => x.Id)
        .FirstOrDefault();
            return Json(lineManagerId);
        }`

Comment: now I think I got the problem. use toList() instead of FirstOrDefault().if still not work share the console.log() again.

Comment: i am getting `undefined` in 2nd dropdown

Comment: please share console.log(data)

Comment: [object Object]{config: Object {...}, data: Array[1], status: 200, statusText: "", xhrStatus: "complete"}

Comment: finally use `<select ng-model="empModel.id" id="" name="Id" 
ng-options="d for d in lineManagerId"> 
</select>` for second dropdown. it will work now.

Comment: its worked now, but stil i get 1st value  empty and second value `1' in 2nd dropdown, i dont want any empty value, value should come directly to dropdown

Comment: yes. now use `$scope.empModel.id = $scope.lineManagerId[0]` instead of `$scope.empModel.id = $scope.lineManagerId[0].lineManagerId` in your angular function

Comment: ok thanks its working fine now. Need to ask another thing is there any option in which when 1st dropdown load data, without click or change 1st dropdown, 2nd dropdown load id based on 1st dropdown name?

Comment: yes that is possible. what you have to do is to call `$scope.GetLineManagerId($scope.empModel.name)` after assigning the value in your first dropdown function. Please make my answer accepted on this question as you have got your solution. thank you. Please give an upvote also

Comment: can you check that question if you can help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48794961/upload-image-in-specified-folder-net-core?noredirect=1#comment84592568_48794961

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an array/enumeration instead of a single value.

```
public JsonResult GetLineManagerId(string LineManagerId)
{
    var lineManagerId = db.Employees
       .Where(x => x.FirstName == LineManagerId)
       .Select(x =>x.Id); // returns an IEnumerable<T> for whatever Id is

    return Json(lineManagerId);
}
```

You have to select a single result like

```
var lineManagerId = db.Employees
   .Where(x => x.FirstName == LineManagerId)
   .Select(x =>x.Id)
   // returns first value or default, i.e. 0 for int, null for string
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: can you guide me how i can get id in text input?

Comment: ts worked fine, but how i can get default value when i select name? currently when i select name i get the in dropdown but 1st value always empty and 2nd value is id